# Help with SQL Query: Is there a cost-efficient way to join multiple tables to one main table?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, join, optimization, query

I have a `main` table set up like this:

| id | table_to_join | table_item_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | products | 123 |
| 2 | products | 577 |
| 3 | products | 344 |
| 4 | products | 1230 |
| 5 | images | 14 |
| 6 | images | 42 |
| 7 | video | 555 |
| 8 | products | 400 |
| 9 | video | 9 |
| 10 | images | 19 |

I have three other tables called `products`, `images` and `videos`. Their Primary ids correspond to those of the table_item_id shown in the `main` table above, which is an indexed column. I would like to query the main table and select those 10 rows, and join those three tables to their corresponding table_item_id to produce one single list showing a variety of different media.

I am looking for an efficient query to do something like this, if it's even possible. I had thought of three Joins, but that seems a bit messy, especially if I start adding more than the three tables in the future. I had also thought of using individual ajax queries on each table after it displays on the homepage, but again that seems a bit messy.

The query below is sort of what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure if there is a better, more cost-efficient method that best fits what I'm intending to do. Let me know what you think.

```
SELECT * FROM main 
  JOIN products ON main.table_item_id = products.id AND table_to_join = 'products' 
  JOIN images ON main.table_item_id = images.id AND table_to_join = 'images' 
  JOIN video ON main.table_item_id = video.id AND table_to_join = 'video' 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Think carefully do you really need in 3 separate slave tables. Maybe one table (maybe even sparse) will be more useful? PS. LIMIT without ORDER BY is strange..

Comment: So, you want to join three tables without using joins, because they seem messy?

Comment: A tip:  The schema pattern with conditional links to different tables is a nightmare to code and terrible for performance.  Re-think.

Comment: @RickJames - How would you handle this, what do you suggest? I'm interested in learning different strategies from people who know more about this than I do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the "product-to-image" a "one-to-many" relationship?  Or "many-to-many"?  (The answer determines how to build the schema for that part.)  Have 3 "Entity" tables (`products`, `images`, `videos`), plus one table per many-to-many "Relationship".

For 1:many:  The column `product_id` is in the table `images`.

For many:many:

```
CREATE TABLE products_images (
    product_id ...,
    image_id ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(product_id, image_id),
    INDEX(image_id, product_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Note that `main` is not needed.

Comment: I'm not sure what the relationship is. The products, images and videos are definitely independent of each other, but are all connected the main table. The `main` table is sort of like a general news feed where each "post" is something random each day. One day, we might attach a video, another other day we might attach a product, and another day is just attach a random image (not related to any product, just a picture of the weather for example).

Comment: @peppy - I would expect a "product" to have "0 or more" (unlimited number) images and videos.  But I don't know if one image/photo can be associated with more than one product.  So, I explained both cases.  Analyze your data.  Search on some of the keywords I have tossed around.